# PhpStorm go to Vue declaration when CMD+clicking on tag

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, phpstorm, laravel-blade

Is there a way in PhpStorm to configure the <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd + Click</kbd> so that clicking on a Vue component in a Blade file goes to its decoration?

For example if I <kbd>Cmd + Click</kbd> on `<user-list...` I would like to go to the `UserList.vue` file.

```php
<!-- index.blade.php -->
<h1>Test</h1>

<user-list :filters="{{ json_encode($filters) }}"></user-list>
```

```js
/* UserData.vue */

// ... vue component here
```

I have a couple plugins installed but could not find the setting.

Comment: Hi! I tried reproducing it, and the navigation on Ctrl-click works for me. Could you provide a sample project and indicate PhpStorm version you use?

Comment: Just yesterday I had it working on another project (CakePHP with .ctp file) but not for blade files with Vite. Might be a configuration issue. I'll investigate and post back on findings.